# Trying to remember this animated kids movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

It has been bothering me for so long, I cant remember loads but this is what I can:

- animation wasn’t very good so late 90s- 2000s kids film
- Definitely involved some sort of ostrich racing or people rode ostriches
- Seem to remember some sort of king or queen in it (might be wrong)
- Quite creepy movie for kids, there was some sort of ‘monster’ character or characters
- There was a scene in this factory (I think they were making like gold or something in there)

Comment: Any other information, such as what country you saw it in, animation style (2D, anime, CG) or anything else would be helpful.

Comment: The "Ostriches" immediately make me think of Nausicaa Valley of the wind..

Comment: @ani the ostriches made me think of Nausicaa Valley of the wind. Its early enough to fit your time line and has monsters, also a character called queen Kushan... the factory scene does not match though but take a look at the trailer, here...  youtube.com/watch?v=6zhLBe319KE note that you can see the ostrich type creatures at about the 30 second mark

Comment: @Anni - An anonymous user has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with the old one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from others, leave comments within this thread, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.