# What is the name of this movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon, animation

- Kids movie from early 2000s, was quite bad animation ( similar to Happily N’ever after 2006)
- Original language was English, watched it in the UK
- Definitely involved some type of ostrich racing or people rode ostriches (seem to remember it was the king or the queen who rode them)
- I remember Rumplestiltskin featuring in it or the name of the movie was a play off the word or something
- Movie is not Nausicaa of The Valley of the wind
- There was a scene in a big factory
- I remember it being quite creepy

Comment: Hi. I'm guessing you're the same user who posted [a question that appears to be asking about the same animated movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275718/trying-to-remember-this-animated-kids-movie) several hours ago. If that's correct, please merge your new account with the previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), so that you can edit these additional details into your original question, rather than abandoning your original question and posting a duplicate instead.

Comment: Incidentally, _Happily N'Ever After_ features 3D animation, not 2D. If you're unsure about the difference, 3D animation involves 3D, computer-generated models, as in _Toy Story_ (1995), while 2D animation involves flat, hand-drawn images, as in _The Lion King_ (1994).

Comment: Although, *The Lion King* is slightly famous for its CG-generated herds for the stampede scene... :-P